# How to split out comma separated data into the same column

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have table in which some first cells contain a comma character. How can copy every row if the first cell contains a comma character to another row?

And I also need to separate first cell value to a new row.

My source table is:

[image]

My destination table is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a macro that loops through each line and then loops through each value within the first column. This basic sample macro requires you to have one of the cells in your table selected, and then creates a new worksheet splitting out your data.

```
Public Sub Expand()

Dim ra As Range
Dim str As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set ra = Selection.CurrentRegion
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
j = 1

For i = 1 To ra.Rows.Count
    For Each str In Split(ra(i, 1), ",")
        ws.Cells(j, 1) = str
        ws.Cells(j, 2) = ra(i, 2)
        j = j + 1
    Next str
Next i

End Sub
```